# FormsAuthenticate + jQuery Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, autenticação

Estou criando uma aplicação que usa o FormsAuthenticate para logar no sistema.

No entanto, gostaria de fazer um tratamento para que em uma requisição ajax (jquery) feita quando o usuário não estiver logado.

Coloquei um `$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {}))`. Porém, quando o servidor informa que não há um login e dá um redirect para a página de login, o `xhr.status` é retornado como 404.

Fazendo uma pesquisa, achei [esse site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/655086/Handling-authentication-specific-issues-for-AJAX-c). A solução dada com `ApplicationAuthorizeAttribute`:`HandleUnauthorizedRequest` é bem o que eu estava imaginando.

Segue a principal classe:método

```
public class ApplicationAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        var user = httpContext.User;

        if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            else
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;

            response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
            response.End();
        }

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Eu só não sei como colocar isso no meu código. (meu inglês não é muito bom). Tem alguma forma dessa classe ser carregada automaticamente para que o overriding possa ser executado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui.
Primeiro, removi do web.config o "`<authorization>`" deixando apenas o "`<authentication>`"

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login" name="nome"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Uma vez criada a classe citada na pergunta, o atributo "ApplicationAuthorize" será criado e poderá ser utilizado.

A partir daí, eu coloquei nas classes/métodos que eu quero que o usuário esteja logado para acessa-los, o atributo. Por exemplo:

```
[ApplicationAuthorize]
public class HomeController : GlobalController
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Com isso, apenas usuários logados poderão acessar a Home.

Isso também me ajudou a fazer um controle no jquery para requisições AJAX feitas quando o usuário perde a sessão, por exemplo. O AJAX recebe um status 401 (e não um 302 seguido de um 200 com o html da página de login, como estava acontecendo antes)